# Setting Default document for subdomain

Tags: c#, seo, subdomain, domain-mapping

My website has a default document pointing to Home.aspx. The site has a folder which is mapped to a sub domain. Is it possible to map the subdomain to the subfolder and have a different default document.

Does 301 redirect affect SEO.